How to disable "Alt" key menu navigation in Ubuntu for VSCode shortcuts
Hello Ask Ubuntu Community,
I frequently use keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio Code (VS Code) to speed up my workflow. However, since switching to Ubuntu, I've noticed an issue with shortcuts that involve the "Alt" key. Every time I press and hold "Alt," the menubar in VSCode activates, showing underlined letters as accelerators. This disrupts my ability to use shortcuts that require the "Alt" key.

According to the Ubuntu documentation, the Alt key has a systemwide function described as follows:

Alt: Hold down the Alt key to reveal accelerators — underlined letters
on menu items, buttons, and other controls. Press Alt plus the
underlined letter to activate a control, just as if you had clicked on
it.

In this case I'm looking for a way to disable this Alt key behavior or at least reassign it to a different key so that I can use Alt key shortcuts within VSCode without triggering the menubar. Ideally I'd like to achieve this without installing third-party software.
